# .next and if not triggering properly

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a carousel that I would be able to just keep growing as time goes by. The DOM structure is

```
<div>
  <div class='active>
     <anchor & image>
  </div>
  <div>
     <anchor & image>
  </div>
</div>
```

I wrote a function that should cycle through the nested divs and when it reaches the end its supposed to go back to the first nested div

```
function carousel(){

setInterval(function(){

    var $active = $('.active');
    var $next = $('.active').next();

    if ( $next == undefined ){

        alert('if triggered');

        $next = $('.active').parent().children(':first-child');

        alert('first child selected');
    };

    alert('removing active class from active')
    $active.removeClass("active");

    alert('adding active class to next')
    $next.addClass('active');

 }, 6000);
}
```

the function removes the active class and assigns it to the next nested div as its supposed to, but in the next interval when the if is supposed to trigger to cycle back to the first nested div, it does not. I thought that next only worked when dealing with siblings, shouldn't the sibling after the lasted nested div be undefined causing it to trigger the if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) will not return undefined if there is no next element, it will return an empty jQuery object, which will result your if condition to fail. So you can check the .length property of the `$next` object to see whether there is a next element

```
if ( $next.length == 0){
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rVbN8/)

Answer (score 0):

No it will never return undefined. It will return an array-like object whose length may be 0 or more. If it could return undefined, then chaining will break and throw exceptions in instances where there are no matches to a selector.